# How to calculate line heights for Noto Simplified Chinese Font in Android?

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin, fonts

I am writing a editor control that has a checkbox for every line of text.

I have a problem calculating the height of the font:

- **NotoSansMonoCJKSC-Regular.otf**

I have done a comparison with **consola.ttf (Consolas)** and taken screenshots here. Pay attention to how the Chinese gradually slips below the guide line.

(Also note that the code has no problem on my Lenovo tablet, or Xiaomi mobile. Only on my Samsung mobile. Also SimHei Chinese font also works fine.)

[image: Noto Simplified Chinese]

[image: Consolas]

My ondraw method in the EditorRenderer is this:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
  int height = (int)GetLineHeight(Utils.SizeUnits.px);
  int movingBaseline = Control.Baseline + CHECK_BOTTOM_MARGIN;
  int scrollY = Control.ScrollY;
  CheckBox cb;

  if (!_checks.CoordsSet)
    _checks.Init(Control.Baseline, height);

  for (int i = 0; i < _checks.Count; i++)
  {
    cb = _checks[i];
    if (!_checks.CoordsSet)
      cb.Init(movingBaseline);

    canvas.DrawRect(cb.Rect.Left, cb.Rect.Top - scrollY, cb.Rect.Right,
            cb.Rect.Bottom - scrollY, _checks.GetPaint(i));

    //font height debug
    canvas.DrawLine(cb.Rect.Left, cb.Rect.Bottom - scrollY,
                    cb.Rect.Left + Control.Width, cb.Rect.Bottom - scrollY,
                    checks.PaintCheckSolid);

    movingBaseline = Control.Baseline + CHECK_BOTTOM_MARGIN + (height * (i + 1));
  }

  _checks.CoordsSet = true;

  base.OnDraw(canvas);
}
```

I'm calculating line heights with the two following methods:

```
protected double GetLineHeight(SizeUnits units = SizeUnits.dp)
{

  return (CalculateLineHeight(editor, units) * _lineSpacingFactor) + 
         _lineAddedPixels;        
}

public double CalculateLineHeight(EditorEx editor, SizeUnits units)
{
    Paint.FontMetrics fm = editor.AndroidTextView.Paint.GetFontMetrics();

    return (fm.Descent - fm.Ascent) / (units == SizeUnits.px ? 1 : Resources.System.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity);
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATED**

I re-tried based on Steve's reply below and tried to use doubles as much as possible, until forced to change to an int or float by a method's parameters:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    double height = GetLineHeight(Utils.SizeUnits.px);
    double movingBaseline = (double)Control.Baseline + CHECK_BOTTOM_MARGIN;
    double scrollY = (double)Control.ScrollY;
    CheckBox cb;

    if (!_checks.CoordsSet)
        _checks.Init(Control.Baseline, height);

    for (int i = 0; i < _checks.Count; i++)
    {
        cb = _checks[i];
        if (!_checks.CoordsSet)
            cb.Init(movingBaseline);

        canvas.DrawRect((float)cb.Rect.Left, 
                        (float)(cb.Rect.Top - scrollY), 
                        (float)cb.Rect.Right,
                        (float)(cb.Rect.Bottom - scrollY), _checks.GetPaint(i));

        //font height debug
        canvas.DrawLine((float)cb.Rect.Left,
                        (float)(cb.Rect.Bottom - scrollY),
                        (float)(cb.Rect.Left + Control.Width),
                        (float)(cb.Rect.Bottom - scrollY), _checks.PaintCheckSolid);

        movingBaseline = (double)Control.Baseline + CHECK_BOTTOM_MARGIN + (height * (double)(i + 1));
    }

    _checks.CoordsSet = true;

    base.OnDraw(canvas);

}
```

Unfortunately the result is still the same:

[image]

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Its an accumulated error, due to converting double to int. `CalculateLineHeight` is returning a non-integer value. Suppose it returns `10.1`. Then `(int)` makes `height` = `10`. A bit too small.

As you go down the screen, `movingBaseline` slowly falls behind the correct value. Eventually, this becomes several pixels behind.

Whether this causes a problem or not depends on the font height, and the device's pixel density.

To fix, remove `(int)`, and use `double` variables:

```cs
double height = GetLineHeight(Utils.SizeUnits.px);
double movingBaseline = ...
```

If any of those methods require `int`, then use `(int)` where you use the value:

```cs
    ... (int)height
or
    ... (int)movingBaseline
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. I've taken into account your suggest, but the outcome is the same. Please see updates above.

Comment: Ok. Then there is nothing wrong with that code. What sets y of each checkbox? _checks[i].y. You may need to put those in an AbsoluteLayout, and manually set their y to correspond to your text.

Comment: Here is the checkbox Init method:   `public void Init(double bottom)
  {
   Rect.Location = new Point(CheckBoxes.LEFTMARGIN, bottom - Height);
   Rect.Height = Height; 
   Rect.Width = Height;

  }`

Comment: **1)** How is the text being rendered? I assumed it was part of OnDraw, but looking closely, I guess it isn't. **2)** Also, what is the current value of `height`?

Comment: The text is being rendered via 
`base.OnDraw(canvas);`. The height is const 36, but I feel this is only the size of the box so shouldn't affect the problem I'm facing, which is more related to the vertical spacing between the boxes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `const` 36. I'm referring to `double height = GetLineHeight(...);` Is that exactly 36? I believe your calculations are correct, but the actual text rendering is, for whatever internal reason, taking slightly more than the alleged line height. This could happen if line height was a fractional value, e.g. `20.9`, and internally it was "rounding up" (e.g. `21`). Actually, it would round up to pixels not DIPs - what is device's pixel `density`? (1, 2, 2.5, 3, or ??). Read its "metrics" to get that.

Comment: I thought you meant the value of the checkbox height. The `GetLineHeight()` code is already pasted above. Pixel density on my tablet is 2, 3 on my problem mobile.

Comment: But most importantly **what is the value of `double height`?**  Is that exactly an integer? Your calculation somehow differs slightly from whatever is internally rendering the text. Its possible that there is "nothing wrong" with yours, but that the internal one is "rounding" slightly differently.

Comment: Sorry, don't get what you mean. As per the code above: `double height = GetLineHeight(Utils.SizeUnits.px);` The `GetLineHeight()` method as mentioned is also defined above.

Comment: I mean put a breakpoint after that line, and tell me the actual number you are seeing for `height`, on the device that has the problem. Not *how* its calculated, but the value that you get, when the problem occurs. 11? 51.32? 3.1415? :)